# Laravel Blade Raw PHP

Tags: php, laravel-blade, laravel-5.8

I need some unconventional help. While this is not how to use the blade template in normal circumstances in this case I am creating Graphs that I am sending with an email. Javascript is not working for emails. I am using Laravel 5.8 wkhtmltopdf 2.14 and it is currently not possible to upgrade. Therefore my last solution is as followed. I am gathering the data and pushing it as an array to the blade template. There I want to use Chart.js and QuickChart to create the graph and display the image in the email.

```
<script src="{{ resource_path('assets/js/Chart.js/Chart.min.js') }}"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ resource_path('assets/js/Chart.js/Chart.min.css') }}" />
<div class="header">
<h2>Report</h2>
</div>
<body>

@php 
    $valueYTD = array(); 
@endphp

@foreach($reportData['downloadURL']['graph_YTD'] as $val)
    @php
        $valueYTD = array_push($val);
    @endphp
@endforeach

@php
   
 $month = ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
      
    $chartConfig = [
            "type"=> "line",
            "data"=> [
                "labels"=> $month,
                    "datasets"  => array([
                        "label" => "Users",
                        "data"  =>  $valueYTD,
                        "fill" => false,
                        "borderColor" =>'blue'
                        ])
                    ]
            ];

    $graphURL = json_encode($chartConfig);
    $chartUrl = 'https://quickchart.io/chart?w=400&h=200&c=' .$graphURL;
@endphp


<img src="{{ $chartUrl }}">

</body>
```

The only issue I have is `$valueYTD` in the `$chartConfig =` body will show as `Undefined variable`. The same is if I declare in the @php body `$valueYTD = $reportData['downloadURL']['graph_YTD']` it will tell me `$reportData` is a `Undefined variable`? I don't know how to declare the array variables in the raw PHP bod of the blade template or how else to go about this.

Comment: That's not how you should use `array_push` here's the doc.: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php

Comment: You are correct that is incorrect, never the less if I fix it to the correct syntax `$val` will change to  `Undefined variable`. If I change it to `$tvuValueYTD[] =$val` same thing.

Comment: Sorry, I missread the issue. When a variable like`$reportData` is not defined in blade, it's usually because it's not passed correctly from the controller. Can you show us how you're returning the view on the controller?

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense and be way easier to just do all that in your controller and then just pass the generated image to the email template?

Comment: Actually @M.Eriksson you are right. After thinking this over and looking at several other posts. I am going to send the JSON `$chartConfig` via the `return $pdf->loadView' and then just set it in the img tag  `<img src="https://quickchart.io/chart?w=400&h=200&c={{ $chartUrl }}">`. I am not sure why I did not think of it before.